# GNU Screen and Emacs

Tags: opensuse, gnu-screen, emacs

I upgraded recently to OpenSuSE 12.1 from 11.3 and now when I open any files in emacs from inside a screen session, I get a blank buffer. Let's say I open it as:

```
emacs myFile.txt
```

it will open to an empty buffer, not the file, and when I attempt to save something, it will ask for a file name to write to. This worked before the upgrade.

I assume screen is the issue here since emacs works fine outside of screen. Is there something I'm missing in the screen settings or is this a bug in something?

Comment: What happens if you use `emacs -nw myfile.txt`?

Comment: Same thing -- I actually have `emacs-nox` installed, so there is no XEmacs/window forwarding issues.

Comment: Are you invoking emacs from a shell or directly from `screen`? Whichever it is, try it the other way. What happens if you set `$TERM` to, say, "xterm"? (I'm grasping at atraws here.)

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the file from the right directory? What happens if you try to open `myFile.txt` from within Emacs?

Comment: @KeithThompson when I changed `$TERM` inside my screen session from `linux`, it's default, to `xterm` it all magically started working! Any idea what that's about? Turn the comment into an answer.

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer, but I'm still bewildered.  With `TERM=linux`, does `emacs myfile.txt` act like it's opening a file that doesn't exist, or is it just not opening anything at all?  Does `vim` work with `TERM=linux`?  Is it possible that you have `emacs` defined as an alias or shell function (what does `type -a emacs` tell you)?

Comment: Vim works fine; emacs is an alias to `emacs -nw` in case I'm on a machine that happens to have XEmacs installed. When I open the file with `linux` as the terminal, it just gives a blank buffer with `*scratch*` at the bottom.

Comment: Also, with `linux`, just typing `emacs` gives a blank buffer while with `xterm` it gives a three line comment about the buffer being for notes and Lisp etc..

Comment: Perhaps the `linux` termcap/terminfo entry causes it to assume the wrong number of lines or columns, or perhaps the wrong wrapping behavior.  How many lines are in `myfile.txt`?  With `TERM=linux emacs`, what happens when you then open `myfile.txt`?  Does `TERM=linux clear` clear the screen?  How about `seq 100 > tmp.txt ; TERM=linux emacs tmp.txt`?  (More grasping at straws, but spelling "straws" correctly this time.)

Comment: The lines vary; it happens with every file. But this one happens to be 51 lines. With `linux`, if I open emacs and then open the file, it all displays correctly. The issue appears to be only when trying to open a file from the command line (and that initial set of comments if I just open emacs, wherever those come from). Same behavior with the `tmp.txt` file generated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer based on the discussion in the comments.

Trial and error indicates that changing `$TERM` from `linux` to `xterm` works around the problem.

I don't know why this would matter.  From your description, with `TERM=linux` it's opening an empty buffer rather than the file, which is not the behavior I'd expect from a bad `$TERM` setting.  And the default `$TERM` under `screen` should be `"screen"` anyway, unless one of your startup scripts changes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my new desktop computer, but my netbook, also running OpenSuSE 12.1 didn't have the problem.  It took a while, but I did track down one difference between the two configurations, and it has solved my problem.  It was this:

On the Hostname/DNS tab of the Network Settings utility (in YaST), I selected Assign Hostname to Loopback IP.